# How to deal with backgrounds that don't look good zoomed out

Tags: html, css

The site I'm working on makes heavy use of a parallel striped background behind certain page elements (it's basically a 1x2 pixel background image that's tiled to create a retro horizontal-banding effect).

When these pages are viewed zoomed-out (e.g. on a phone), the user sees moire patterns which ruins the effect.

How can I either (a) degrade to a flat background color when the user views the page zoomed out, or preferably (b) force the background to be rendered 1:1 regardless of zoom?

Comment: If you want to target particular element like phone, you can use media query and overwrite your background styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a single image (not a tile), you'd be able to use the `background-size: 100%` CSS property to force the browser to not exceed the image dimensions.

Since you *are* using a tile, you need to control the size of the display window to control the number of tiles -- you could use the below META tag to prevent zooming on mobile (in or out), and use media queries to customize CSS styling:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
   initial-scale=1,
   maximum-scale=1, 
   user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In a responsive website or mobile targeted website it will be good to display zoom. If you do not want this you can control the background image display through media queries targeting zoomed devices.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    your css can come here
}
```